# Unit test fail with No EntityManager available

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I have a unit test that covers a `@transactional` method, however, I'm getting No EntityManager when I try to run it. As I've seen in many places, I put the `@Transactional` annotation before the test method, I tried also before the whole class, but still had the same issue.

```java
@Transactional
@RunWith(KronosSpringTestRunner.class)
@ClassesToTest(classes = {
      
}, bindAllMocks = true
)
public class ShiftAuditJPADataReadUsingIndexServiceTest {

    @Inject
    private ShiftAuditJPADataReadUsingIndexService underTest;


    @Before
    public void setup() {

        when(entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)).thenReturn(sessionMock);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_findByEmployee() {
    

        List<ShiftAudit> expected = Collections.singletonList(new ShiftAudit());

        when(properties.getProperty(QUERY_BATCH_SIZE, DEFAULT_QUERY_BATCH_SIZE)).thenReturn(DEFAULT_QUERY_BATCH_SIZE);

        when(sessionMock.createSQLQuery(anyString())).thenReturn(sqlQuery);
        when(sqlQuery.setResultTransformer(any(ResultTransformer.class))).thenReturn(queryMock);
        when(jpaDataReadServiceHelper.queryList(sqlQuery, employeeIds, scheduleStartDate, scheduleEndDate, false)).thenReturn(expected);

        Collection<ShiftAudit> actual = underTest.findByEmployee(employeeId, scheduleStartDate, scheduleEndDate, false);

        assertEquals(expected, actual);
        verify(sessionMock).createSQLQuery(anyString());
    }
```

Comment: Place your code here. It's tough to identify problems just by reading your words..

Comment: @Ryednap I updated the post, do you have a suggestion ?

Comment: Are you wiring `entityManager` in your test class? As you are having the usage of that in your `setup()` method

Comment: I added @Autowired, but still getting the same error.

Comment: For the wiring to work you need to annotate your test class with `@SpringBootTest`. By default, it is not injected. Kindly confirm if this solves your problem.